# Textbox OnTextChanged event not triggered using a calendar control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using a calendar control from internet. I don't know much about javascript, the calendar is for phone use - scroll up and down to select the date and time and then need to click 'Confirm' or 'Cancel'.
The relevant js code from my view is:

```
...
<li id="dateconfirm">Confirm</li>'
...

        function bindButton(){
        resetIndex();
        $("#dateconfirm").unbind('click').click(function () {   
            var datestr = $("#yearwrapper ul li:eq("+indexY+")").html().substr(0,$("#yearwrapper ul li:eq("+indexY+")").html().length-1)+"-"+
                      $("#monthwrapper ul li:eq("+indexM+")").html().substr(0,$("#monthwrapper ul li:eq("+indexM+")").html().length-1)+"-"+
          $("#daywrapper ul li:eq("+Math.round(indexD)+")").html().substr(0,$("#daywrapper ul li:eq("+Math.round(indexD)+")").html().length-1);
           if(datetime){
                 if(Math.round(indexS)===1){//afternoon
                    $("#Hourwrapper ul li:eq("+indexH+")").html(parseInt($("#Hourwrapper ul li:eq("+indexH+")").html().substr(0,$("#Hourwrapper ul li:eq("+indexH+")").html().length-1))+12)
                 }else{
                    $("#Hourwrapper ul li:eq("+indexH+")").html(parseInt($("#Hourwrapper ul li:eq("+indexH+")").html().substr(0,$("#Hourwrapper ul li:eq("+indexH+")").html().length-1)))
                 }
                 datestr+=" "+$("#Hourwrapper ul li:eq("+indexH+")").html().substr(0,$("#Minutewrapper ul li:eq("+indexH+")").html().length-1)+":"+
                         $("#Minutewrapper ul li:eq("+indexI+")").html().substr(0,$("#Minutewrapper ul li:eq("+indexI+")").html().length-1);
                     indexS=0;
            }

            if(Ycallback===undefined){
                 if(docType){that.val(datestr);}else{that.html(datestr);}
            }else{
                                Ycallback(datestr);
            }
            $("#datePage").hide(); 
            $("#dateshadow").hide();
        });
        $("#datecancle").click(function () {
            $("#datePage").hide(); 
    $("#dateshadow").hide();
            Ncallback(false);
        });
    }
```

When the focus is on the textbox it pops up a calendar. Originally its .html is:

```
$(function(){
$('#Time').date({theme:"datetime"});
});

<div>Date Set:<input id="Time"/></div>
```

To change it from .html to .aspx. I did some modification:

```
$(function () {
$("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").date({ theme: "datetime" });
});   

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" BorderWidth="0" OnTextChanged="txtDate_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Font-Size="20" placeholder="Select Date"/>
```

I want to trigger **OnTextChanged** event when I select a date/time and click 'Confirm' but it is not triggered although the text on the textbox has changed accordingly. Why is that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the textbox control, "The event is only raised if the text is changed by the user; the event is not raised if the text is changed programmatically."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Actually when I use another calendar control called 'datepicker' which doesn't use a 'Confirm' or 'Cancel' button, the event can be raised.